# My citations are not showing up

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker, bibdesk

I'm using TexMaker to write my thesis with Classic Thesis template, I have just started, but the first cite is not showing up, is like this:

```
\begin{quote}
Called \textbf{classification} or \textbf{inductive} learning in machine learning. This type of learning is analogues to human learning from past experience to gain new knowledge in order to improve our ability to perform real-world tasks. However, since computers do not have ``experiences", machine learning learns from data, which are collected in the past and represent past experiences in some real-world applications. 
\end{quote}\cite{webDataMining}
```

I have the Biblography.bib created with bibDesk on OSX and it has the entry:

```
@book{webDataMining,
    Address = {http://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-3-642-19460-3},
    Author = {Liu, Bing},
    Date-Added = {2015-01-05 07:57:47 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-01-05 08:00:22 +0000},
    Edition = {2},
    Keywords = {Datamining; Supervised Learning; Support Vector Machines; Web},
    Number = {2},
    Publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
    Series = {2},
    Title = {Web Data Mining: Exploring Hyperlinks, Contents, and Usage Data},
    Volume = {2},
    Year = {2011},
    Bdsk-File-1 = {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}}
```

And finally it has the commands:

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
```

Is not using the new file I created, is using the old one though I have changed the name to Bibliography-1.bib for the old one and mine as Bibliography.bib, any help? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you run `bibtex` or `biber` at all? Is there a `\printbibliography` (or the `bibtex` equivalent command) at all?

Comment: Hi, I have just exported the bibDesk file as the new Bibliography, so as Bibliogarphy.bib as that file has it and no, there is no \printbibliography command called from the template, there is just \bibliography{Bibliography}  % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"
 and some others

Comment: it has \usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography, thats why I exported it

Comment: I have no idea what `bibdesk` (because I never needed it so far), but you have to run `bibtex` then (not biber!) if you have `\bibliography` as the bib-inclusion command

Comment: This is http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net the template is using natbib no bibtex so I have just exported it.

Comment: I don't use such software (and I am not using MacOS at all) ;-)

Comment: I don't think is a software issue, I think is something more because the template is not updating with the new file it keeps using the old one and I do not know how is getting it if is renamed already.